What's the canonical way to use pytest to assert that a string matches a regex AND get good error reporting?
unittest module has the assertRegexMatches assert, but the beauty of pytest is that it lets you use more natural asserts. But
assert re.search(pattern, str) is not None

is not so nice and doesn't provide good info. I tried searches but they all lead to the special use of regex is pytest.raises, not for checking plain old regexes.

assert takes an optional second argument, a string to use as the error message when the assertion fails. Doesn't pytest use this?

You can just use
assert re.search(pattern, _str), f"{_str} does not match {pattern}"


Fair enough. I just was thinking that for things like assert list_1 == list_2 you get fancy diffs from pytest and wondering if the same exited for regexes.
